# Why is my reactive data frame in R shiny not updating correctly when using an observeEvent?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, observers, shiny-reactivity

In the below code, I use `observeEvent(input$delSeries3, {...})` and `renderUI(selectInput(...))` to allow the user to delete selected columns from the reactive data frame `emptyTbl()`. When running that `observeEvent()` and sending the data frame values (after deleting a column) into the global environment with `test <<- tmp`, for testing purposes, it works fine. I review the resulting post-deletion values of the `test` object in the R studio console and they look fine. However, when I comment out that `test <<- tmp` and replace it with `emptyTbl(tmp)` (currently commented out in the below code) in an attempt to send those `tmp` values back into the reactive space and re-render the table to reflect the column deletion, the code no longer works as intended: it incorrectly automatically deletes the first column and otherwise gives strange results. I tried wrapping with `isolate()` in different places and this didn't help.

The code is supposed to allow the user to add columns with action button "addSeries" (this works), allow the user to manually edit cells using the rhandsontable package and retain those edits (this works, using `hot_to_r(input$hottable)`), and allow the user to delete selected columns with action button "delSeries" (not quite working).

What am I doing wrong here with column deletion? Something is missing in my understanding of reactivity and observers.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,24,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  useShinyjs(), 
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(1,actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')),
    column(1,actionButton("delSeries","Delete",width = '70px')),
    column(3,hidden(uiOutput("delSeries2"))) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  emptyTbl <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {emptyTbl(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(emptyTbl(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,24,0,1))
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    emptyTbl(cbind(emptyTbl(), newCol))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delSeries3, {
    tmp <- emptyTbl()                                       # values of reactive DF emptyTbl sent to tmp
    delCol <- input$delSeries3                              # specify column to delete from selectInput() choice
    tmp <- tmp[ , !(names(tmp) %in% delCol), drop = FALSE]  # delete selected column
    newNames <- sprintf("Series %d",seq(1:ncol(tmp)))       # generate new column header sequence
    names(tmp) <- newNames                                  # assign new column headers to DF
    test <<- tmp                                            # send tmp DF to global environment for testing only
    # emptyTbl(tmp)                                           # sends values of tmpDF back to reactive DF emptyTbl
  })

  observeEvent(input$delSeries, show("delSeries2"))
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, hide("delSeries2")) 
  
  output$delSeries2 <- renderUI(selectInput("delSeries3", label = NULL,
                                   choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable)), 
                                   selected = "")
                                )

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by default the `selected` value of a `selectInput` defaults to the first element in the choices list when not specified. Hence, when creating `"delSeries3"` the selected argument is the the first column or series which triggers the `observeEvent` and deletes that column. One easy fix would be to set `multiple=TRUE` in which case `selected` defaults to no values. A second option would be to "slow down the app" by e.g. adding another `actionButton` which the user has to click after selecting the column(s) he wants to delete.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame("Series 1" = c(1, 24, 0, 1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c("Term A", "Term B", "Term C", "Term D")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  useShinyjs(),
  rHandsontableOutput("hottable"), br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(1, actionButton("addSeries", "Add", width = "70px")),
    column(1, actionButton("delSeries", "Delete", width = "70px")),
    column(3, hidden(uiOutput("delSeries2")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  emptyTbl <- reactiveVal(mydata)

  observeEvent(input$hottable, {
    emptyTbl(hot_to_r(input$hottable))
  })

  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(emptyTbl(), rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1, 24, 0, 1))
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    emptyTbl(cbind(emptyTbl(), newCol))
  })

  observeEvent(input$delSeries3, {
    tmp <- emptyTbl() # values of reactive DF emptyTbl sent to tmp
    delCol <- input$delSeries3 # specify column to delete from selectInput() choice
    tmp <- tmp[, !(names(tmp) %in% delCol), drop = FALSE] # delete selected column
    newNames <- sprintf("Series %d", seq(1:ncol(tmp))) # generate new column header sequence
    names(tmp) <- newNames # assign new column headers to DF
    # test <<- tmp                                            # send tmp DF to global environment for testing only
    emptyTbl(tmp) # sends values of tmpDF back to reactive DF emptyTbl
  })

  observeEvent(input$delSeries, show("delSeries2"))
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, hide("delSeries2"))

  output$delSeries2 <- renderUI(selectInput("delSeries3",
    label = NULL,
    choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable)),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```